# How to modify my python multi-process program？

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing, pytorch, opticalflow

I try to process the image files in order from the directory /base_path. The /base_path directory contains 78 folders, named 00001-00078. In these 78 files, each has 1000 folders, each named 0001-1000, and each directory contains three pictures, named im1.png, im2.png, im3.png, and the requirement is through func( ) to generate the optical flow ft1.flo of img2->img1 and the optical flow of im3->im1 in the /output directory. Therefore, the dataset is very large. I have tried to use multi-process methods to speed up. The program has been running without errors, but there is no output file, and the CPU utilization rate is also very low. I guess my multi-process part is written incorrectly. Can anyone help me, thank you very much! Below is part of my code.

```
def func(list):
    #os.system('cp /code/pytorch-liteflownet/network-default.pytorch /root/.cache/torch/checkpoints/') #copy pretrained-model
    img2 = cv2.imread(list[0])
    img1 = cv2.imread(list[1])
    img3 = cv2.imread(list[2])
    tenFirst = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.ascontiguousarray(img2.transpose(2, 0, 1).astype(numpy.float32) * (1.0 / 255.0)))
    tenSecond = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.ascontiguousarray(img1.transpose(2, 0, 1).astype(numpy.float32) * (1.0 / 255.0)))
    tenThird = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.ascontiguousarray(img3.transpose(2, 0, 1).astype(numpy.float32) * (1.0 / 255.0)))
    tenOutput = estimate(tenFirst, tenSecond)
    tenOutput2 = estimate(tenFirst, tenThird)
    objOutput = open(list[3], 'wb')
    objOutput2 = open(list[4], 'wb')

    numpy.array([ 80, 73, 69, 72 ], numpy.uint8).tofile(objOutput)
    numpy.array([ tenOutput.shape[2], tenOutput.shape[1] ], numpy.int32).tofile(objOutput)
    numpy.array(tenOutput.numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0), numpy.float32).tofile(objOutput)

    numpy.array([ 80, 73, 69, 72 ], numpy.uint8).tofile(objOutput2)
    numpy.array([ tenOutput.shape[2], tenOutput.shape[1] ], numpy.int32).tofile(objOutput2)
    numpy.array(tenOutput.numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0), numpy.float32).tofile(objOutput2)
    objOutput.close()
    objOutput2.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_path = '/data/dachunkai/vimeo_triplet/sequences/'
    datalist = []
    for i in range(1, 79):
        for j in range(1, 1001):
            path_in = base_path + str(i).rjust(5, '0') + '/' + str(j).rjust(4, '0')
            path_out = '/output' + '/data' + '/' + str(i).rjust(5, '0') + '/' + str(j).rjust(4, '0')

            arguments_strFirst = path_in + '/im2.png'
            arguments_strSecond = path_in + '/im1.png'
            arguments_strThird = path_in + '/im3.png'
            arguments_strOut = path_out + '/ft0.flo'
            arguments_strOut2 = path_out + '/ft1.flo'
            datalist.append([arguments_strFirst, arguments_strSecond, arguments_strThird, arguments_strOut, arguments_strOut2])

    cores = cpu_count()
    print('cpu_count', cores)
    pool = Pool(cores)
    pool.map(func, datalist)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `func` with `datalist[0]` as an argument without using multiprocessing to see if you get output then?

Comment: I have tried func with datalist[0], and it an correctly works. So what's the problem with my multiprocessing?

Comment: If your arguments are just strings, it *appears* that your multiprocessing code is correct (at least what you have shown -- this is *not* a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since you have omitted a lot of imports and other code at the global level). That is not to say this would necessarily perform better using multiprocessing, but I would expect you to at least get output and I have no explanation as to why you do not. Your indentation is *definitely* wrong under `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: I see you are executing the `cp` command. Am I correct in assuming you are running this under linux/unix? What does it mean for every process to be executing this command over and over in parallel? Can this be causing a conflict? Should this be done just once?